# what is the difference between toggleClass("class"), attr("class", class) and addClass in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


 $("div").focusin(function(){
        $(this).attr('class', 'focusedin');
    });

 $("div").focusout(function(){
        $(this).attr('class', 'focusedout');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style>
  .focusedin {
    background: green;
  }
  .focusedout {
    background: blue;
  }
  </style>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
 First name: <input type="text"><br>
 Last name: <input type="text">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to learn how to give different backgrounds to input elements when focusedin and focused out, however I realised that using the three of these will have different effect, I understand the difference between toggleclass and addclass, but I am not sure why both of them will not work properly while attr() will work.

```
    <div>  
     First name: <input type="text"><br>  
     Last name: <input type="text">  
    </div>    



//jQuery used initially and didn't work


      $("div").focusin(function(){
          $(this).toggleClass("focusedin");
      });

      $("div").focusout(function(){
          $(this).toggleClass("focusedout");
      });

    }); 


//second jquery that worked


$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").focusin(function(){  
        $(this).attr('class', 'focusedin');  
    });  

 $("div").focusout(function(){  
        $(this).attr('class', 'focusedout');  
    });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

`toggleClass` toggles a class. So when the class you provide is already present, it gets removed and visa versa.

`addClass` just adds an extra class to the element. If the class is already present, it will not get added again. The counterpart of this function is `removeClass`

`attr` just sets (or gets) an attribute. So if you use it to set the class attribute, it will overwrite any classes that are already present. It is probably not a good idea to use this one in your case.

In your code, you forget to remove the old state. So you have 2 options:

```
  $("div").focusin(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("focusedin focusedout");
  });

  $("div").focusout(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("focusedout focusedin");
  });
```

This assumes your "focusedout" class is already present in the initial html. An alterative would be:

```
  $("div").focusin(function(){
      $(this).addClass("focusedin")
             .removeClassClass("focusedout");
  });

  $("div").focusout(function(){
      $(this).addClass("focusedout")
             .removeClassClass("focusedin");
  });
```

This makes no assumptions for the initial markup. I also believe it is a bit clearer from the code what exactly it does. It is a bit longer though.

Comment: for some reason the only way that work ia .attr(), both of your answers will have different effects from attr, I think my question was not clear enough, so I included a snippet. thanks for answering